# VBA macro different results to manual filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro using VBA but the results I get when I use the macro differ from when I filter manually.
Is there something wrong in the code which would cause it not to function correctly? Some columns have multiple criteria which I couldn't do just using the Record Macro function. I wasn't sure if I would to use arrays instead.
Column numbers are all correct, or would I be better using the columns titles in row1?

```
Sub Debut()
'
' DebutDestroyer Macro
' This macro will filter for VDW Win %, Class, VDW Form, RP Rating, J&T, Race Type and Contender
'
Dim last As Long
last = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BU" & last)
    .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Flat Turf"
    .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="NH Flat"
    .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Hurdle Turf"
    .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Hunter Chase"
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="1"
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="2"
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="3"
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="4"
    .AutoFilter Field:=38, Criteria1:="100"
    .AutoFilter Field:=43, Criteria1:="0"
    .AutoFilter Field:=43, Criteria1:="1"
    .AutoFilter Field:=71, Criteria1:="="
    .AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:=">=30"
    .AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:="0"
    .AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:="="
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">=80"
    .AutoFilter Field:=50, Criteria1:="1"
    .AutoFilter Field:=50, Criteria1:="2"
    .AutoFilter Field:=50, Criteria1:="3"
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot to add that the fields with multiple criteria are all meant to be using OR, so as an example, field 41 would need to be >=30 or zero or blank. Similarly with the other fields. Had researched using arrays, but wasn't sure

Comment: hi, for two criterias u can use    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="=1", Operator _
        :=xlOr, Criteria2:="=2", for more than 2 u have to use an array .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("1", "2", "3","4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: Perfect Luis. All bar one macro works fine now. The one not working has (">=30", "0", "=") in the array and a 1004 error stops on that line. Any idea why that would be? Is it not permissable to use >= in an array?

Comment: @Luis Curado, for some reason one of the lines in the macro generates a 1004 error  message. It contains the following

 `.AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:=Array(">=30", "0", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Any suggestions on how to alter it so it works correctly?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating the Criteria1 for each column multiple times is creating the problem i guess. Instead of setting it in each row like this:

```
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="1"
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="2"
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="3"
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="4"
```

you can replace it with an array of values:

```
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("1", "2", "3", "4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that. That has resolved the issue in all but one macro. All bar one work fine, but one spits out a 1004 error on this line

`.AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:=Array(">=30", "0", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues`